# How to Dynamically Build an Active Record Query with Rails Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking for a better way to dynamically build a active record query without making a sql string.

The following method does a new search for every word in the search_str and returns the records that are returned by all the search scopes.

```
  scope :multi_search, ->(search_str){
    query = ''
    if search_str.present?
      search_str.split(' ').each do |x|
        query += ".search('#{x}')"
      end
      eval(query[1..-1])
    else
      all
    end
  }
```

It works, but this is not a clean implementation with the use of eval. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a model method:

```
def self.multi_search(your_params)
  scope = Model.scoped({})
  your_params.split(' ').map{|v| scope = scope.search(v)}
  scope
end
```

Comment: your search method or scope must receive an array. you not need call the method for each word

Comment: This is pretty good solution but it would be nice to find a version where I can use rails scopes instead of method. Should it be `self.multi_search` though?

Comment: Yes. must be a class method and allow chain other scopes in the controller for example.... Model.multi_search(your_params).page()